# Roles/Permission for user to Create Email and Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, roles

Are there out of the box Roles to allow a user to Create an Email. Then select a Data Extension and finally Send.

We had Content Creator and Marketing Cloud Content Editor/Publisher.

But the user can not select a Sending DE.

Comment: have you checked the user permissions under roles?

Comment: Yes, it looks like if I add View to Data Extensions we are good. I was just wondering if there was a Role already created for this type of User.